# Rails two connected models in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose we have the Lyric model:

```
class Lyric < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
end
```

and the Song model:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist, :through => :artistsong

  belongs_to :album

  has_one :lyric
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lyric   #is this needed?
end
```

The migration script for songs:

```
class CreateSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :songs do |t|
      t.integer :track
      t.string :name
      t.references :album
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :songs, :album_id
  end
end
```

The migration script for lyrics:

```
class CreateLyrics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lyrics do |t|
      t.text :lyric
      t.references :song
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :lyrics, :song_id
  end
end
```

And suppose I have a song called "song 1" and with its lyrics attached in the database.

so the song table:

```
|id|name                |
-------------------------
|1 |song1               |
```

and the lyrics table:

```
|id|song_id|lyrics              |
---------------------------------
|1 |1      |blahblah            |
```

in the song_controller.rb's edit method:

```
# GET /songs/1/edit
def edit
  @song = Song.find(params[:id], :include=>:lyric)
end
```

This is the view to edit the song: (after the fix suggested by Matteo)

```
<%= form_for(@song) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <% f.fields_for :song_text do |child_form| %>
    <%= child_form.label :lyrics %><br />
    <%= child_form.text_field :lyrics %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

if I do:

```
<%= debug(@song.lyric) %>
```

I can see the contents of the lyrics:

```
--- !ruby/object:Lyric
attributes:
  id: 1
  song_text: hid
  song_id: 2
  created_at: 2012-02-07 00:59:14.000000000Z
  updated_at: 2012-02-07 07:21:57.000000000Z
```

But in the view the textarea for lyrics disappeared completely...

I want to be able to edit the song's name and the lyrics in the same form, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Added the migration script for lyrics and songs

Comment: you can try to change the name of the field containing the lyric in the table lyrics and use the new one in the fields_for. Maybe something like song_text or lyric_text.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a first time ruby user, I think I changed the proper places.

Comment: Your question is incorrect; you state the lyrics table has a `lyrics` attribute, not a `song_text` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the :lyric in the fields_for because the name of the field in the table lyrics is not lyric but lyrics

```
<% f.fields_for :lyric do |child_form| %>
  <%= child_form.label :lyrics %><br />
  <%= child_form.text_field :lyrics %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks much! got it working with:
 <%= f.fields_for :lyric do |l| %>
    <%= l.label :song_text %><br />
    <%= l.text_area :song_text %>
 <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= child_form.label :lyric %><br />
<%= child_form.text_field :lyric %>
```

Should both be `:lyrics` *plural*, not `:lyric`

Comment: there is  `has_one :lyric` relation

Comment: @SandipRansing Yes, and the `fields_for :lyric` has already selected the `lyric` association. The `Lyric` object has one field, called `lyrics`, which is what needs to be typed into the `label` and `text_field` helpers. The answer stands, and is correct as you can see from the accepted answer.